# Debezium not honouring table.include.list

Tags: postgresql, debezium, change-data-capture

I am trying to work with Debezium engine and postgresql connector to listen to my postgres DB changes. The configurations:

```
io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
                .with("name", "author-connector")
                .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector")
                .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
                .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/tmp/offsets.dat")
                .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
                .with("database.hostname", "localhost")
                .with("database.port", "5432")
                .with("database.user", postgres)
                .with("database.password", postgres)
                .with("database.dbname", postgres)
                .with("database.include.list", postgres)
                .with("schema.include.list", "admin")
                .with("table.include.list", "admin.connector")
                .with("include.schema.changes", "true")
                .with("database.server.name", "author-server")
                .with("database.history", "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
                .with("database.history.file.filename", "/tmp/dbhistory.dat")
                .with("plugin.name", "pgoutput")
                .with("signal.enabled.channels", "source")
                .with("topic.prefix", "admin")
                .with("quarkus.http.port", "7001")
                .with("signal.data.collection", "admin.signal_table")
                .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
                .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/tmp/offsets.dat")
                .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
                .build();
```

I am using `debzium-embedded` `version: 2.4.1.Final`. The connection is able to setup correctly.

But, any change (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`) in `admin.connector` are somehow not getting captured.

Again if I am trying incremental snapshot using my signal table, I get the below error:
`ractIncrementalSnapshotChangeEventSource : Schema not found for table 'admin.connector', known tables [admin.signal_table]`

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out I only need to keep `schema.include.list` which enables debezium to track all tables in the schema list. The `table.include.list` is not honoured in this case.